# How to get rid of column border of gridview using CSS

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to manually style a gridview in ASP.NET to make it look like one of the default gridview styles. the default style is like this -
[image: Default Gridview Style]

I have come pretty close. after applying my own style to a barebone gridview control, it look like this -
[image: Custom CSS]

But I can't seem to remove the white borders in the header section of the Gridview.

My SCSS looks like this -

```
table{
    &.table-grid{
        color:Black;
        background-color:White;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style:None;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        font-size:10pt;
        width:100%;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        td {
            border: none;
            border-top: 1px solid $table-bg-color;
        }
        tr {
            border-collapse:collapse;
            &:first-child{
                color:White;
                background-color:$table-bg-color;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            th{
                border-collapse:collapse;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my gridview attributes are -

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" CssClass="table-grid" EnableViewState="false" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
```

can anyone tell me how to get rid of these white borders?

here's a JsFiddle <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UVRC7/)**</kbd>

Comment: can you show a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
th{
                border-collapse:collapse;
                border-width: 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand slightly on the previous answer:

```
th{
border-collapse:collapse;
border-width: 0;
text-align: left;
}
```

To get the column headings to line up nicely too :)